# Рекурсий вывод текста из тегов в DOM

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

#### Дано задание

> При нажатии кнопки запускается функция t3. Функция t3, с помощью рекурсивной функции r3 должна очистить текст внутри z-3 от тегов span, b, i и p. Должен остаться только текст со знаками препинания в переменной out. Функция t3 должна возвращать out.

#### И мое решение

```js
function t3(elem) {
  let out = '';
  r3(elem);

  function r3(element) {
    let innerElements = element.children;
    Array.from(innerElements).forEach(item => r3(item));
    return element;

  }
  out += elem.textContent;
  return out;
}

document.querySelector('.b-3').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let z3 = document.querySelector('.z-3');
  document.querySelector('.out-3').textContent = t3(z3);

});
```

```html
<div class="z-3 section">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum </span><span>dolor </span><i>sit</i><b>amet. </b></p>
  <p><em>Consectetur </em><b>adipiscing </b><span>elit, sed do </span><b>eiusmod </b><i>tempor incididuntut labore.</i></p>
</div>
<button class="b-3">Запустить</button>
<div class="out-3"></div>
```

#### Вопрос

Задание то я решил. Но я бы хотел узнать - может есть альтернативный подход, чтобы удалить все именно в HTML коде?

Comment: Гораздо удобнее иметь описание такого вида - у меня есть вот это, нужно получить вот такое.

Comment: Я вас огорчу. Ваш код **абсолютно** не работает рекурсивно. Удалите все из функции `t3`, оставьте только `return elem.textContent`. Все будет работать так же как в вашем примере. Так что задание вы не решили.

Comment: @Kuvlax, чем не устраивает сразу взять текст `console.log(z3.textContent)`? См. мой пример...

Answer (score 0):

Твой код можно сократить...

```js
function t3(elem) {
  let innerElements = elem.children;
  if (innerElements.length) return [...innerElements].reduce((s, item) => s + t3(item), '');
  return elem.textContent;
}

document.querySelector('.b-3').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const z3 = document.querySelector('.z-3');
  console.log(z3.textContent)
  document.querySelector('.out-3').textContent = t3(z3);

});
```

```html
<div class="z-3 section">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum </span><span>dolor </span><i>sit</i><b>amet. </b></p>
  <p><em>Consectetur </em><b>adipiscing </b><span>elit, sed do </span><b>eiusmod </b><i>tempor incididuntut labore.</i></p>
</div>
<button class="b-3">Запустить</button>
<div class="out-3"></div>
```

Comment: Зачем все эти танцы с бубнами если можно просто `return elem.textContent`. К тому же в задаче написано **очистить рекурсивно**.

Comment: Убрал лишнее... У меня есть рекурсия.